# Use class in attribut for parameters c#

Tags: c#, class, attributes

I have a class like this :

```
public class TEST1 : TEST1Role
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use this class in attribute for make something like this :

```
public class startup()
{
    [CustomAttribute(isActive = true)]
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

But I don't want to create the attribute with all the members where them are previously declared in my class TEST1

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE 1**

I want this imagine :

```
private TEST1 filters;

public CustomAttribute(TEST1 filters)
{
    this.filters = filters;
}
```

and when I use it on a method, I want to get access of all members of the class TEST1 through the attribute parameters

But unfortunately this is not working ...

Comment: How is `CustomAttribute` related to `TEST1`? Apart from this while you **declare** that those members exist in your attribute-class, you don´t give them any **value**, so what exactly do you want to avoid here?

Comment: Actually, he is empty... I mean i don't know how to make a relation for use all the members of the class TEST1 in the Custom Attribute for use them later, But, the finality is to use the parameters passed in attribute to check if a user have one or all in permission described

Comment: @MaximeArchie are you wanting to use TEST1 as a property for startup() ?

Comment: @TerryTyson, no i want to use the class TEST1 as attribute for method

Comment: I suggest to read about attributes and how to implement them before. First most obvious thing here is, that your `TEST1`-class should derive from `Attribute` in order to be usable as an attribute. Then you can do `[TEST1(isActive= true)]`. Furtheremore the class should be named `TEST1Attribute`.

Comment: @MaximeArchie see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes

Comment: @HimBromBeere, i understand and t i updated the post, TEST 1 inherit already of a class and cannot define it as a attribute

Comment: So if `CustomAttribute` needs an instance of `TEST1`, you surely have to provide one: `CustomAttribute(myInstanceOfTest1Class)`. However be aware that attributes can only use compile-time constants.

Answer (score 1):

You´re mixing a lot of things here, so I´m going to clearfiy that mess a bit. An `Attribute` is a fix thing in .NET, referring to the `Attribute`-class that enables you to use your class as decorator on any member, class or whatever:

```
class CustomAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
class MyClass
{
    [CustomAttribute(MyProperty = "Hello World")]
    void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

However attributes are a compiler-feature (however they are evaluated at runtime). So you can use only compile-time constants, e.g. a number or a string-literal as shown above. You seem to have a dependecy of your attribute-class `CustomAttribute` to a complex object of type `TEST1`. However such an object does not exist at compile-time, which is why you cannot use it as parameter within `CustomAttribute`s constructor.

So instead of providing a complex object you can deconstruct your object to its members:

```
class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly TEST1 filters;
    public CustomAttribute(bool isActive, bool isAllowed) 
    {
        this.filters = new TEST1 { isActive = isActive, isAllowed = isAllowed };
    }
}
```

Now you can use it this way:

```
class MyClass
{
    [CustomAttribute(isActive = true, isAllowed = false)]
    void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```